# Constraint to bottom layout guide with TabBar issue

Tags: ios, xcode, constraints, autolayout

I have UITabBarController based iPad app with containerView on the first tab. The containerView has standard vertical spacing to bottom layout guide. When I tap on the second tab and then go back to the first tab, my container moves down by 56 pts, the height of the tabBar and is then covered by the tabBar.

I made 3 screenshots to illustrate that. The third screenshot shows hidden tabBar after the jump between tabs. It looks like the bottom layout guide went down to the edge. What is going on here?

[image]

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I'm not sure about what happened here, but I think that this could help:

[image]

Uncheck Under bottom bar in your UIViewController properties

Hope that will help!

Comment: I had this issue with top, bottom, right and left. with your answer I solve top and bottom issue, but do you have any solution for right and left constraint? @Nicolas Bonnet

Comment: Which element is creating the problem for left and right constraint?

Answer (score 3):

Nicolas Bonnet's answer of unchecking "Extend Edges Under Bottom Bar" didn't work for me. In my case the problem seemed to be that I was setting the bottom constraint of my view equal to the Bottom Layout Guide.

So, instead, I aligned the bottom edges of my button and the ViewController's view as shown below.

Select both your view to pin to the bottom and the main view:

[image: View Selection Image]

Then tap the Align selection menu at the bottom right of Interface Builder and select Bottom Edges:

[image]